# How to measure if a program was run in parallel over multiple cores in Linux?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, benchmarking, perf

I want to know if my program was run in parallel over multiple cores. I can get the **perf** tool to report how many cores were used in the computation, but not if they were used **at the same time** (in parallel).

How can this be done?

Comment: What is your program? Did you write it? Do you have its source code? What is the purpose of your program? Is it using pthreads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the command 
    `top` 
in another terminal while the program is running. It will show the usage of all the cores on your machine.

Comment: It might be a good solution. When top reports a CPU usage of 200%, will it always mean that two cores are being used? And so on?

Comment: A small script running top in batch mode and some awk magic did the job.

Answer (score 1):

A few possible solutions:

- Use [`htop`](http://hisham.hm/htop/) on another terminal as your program is being executed. `htop` shows the load on each CPU separately, so on an otherwise idle system you'd be able to tell if more than one core is involved in executing your program.

  It is also able to show each thread separately, and the overall CPU usage of a program is aggregated, which means that parallel programs will often show CPU usage percentages over 100%.
- Execute your program using the `time` command or shell builtin. For example, under `bash` on my system:

  ```
  $ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 2>/dev/null | time -p xz -T0 > dev/null
  real 0.85
  user 2.74
  sys 0.14
  ```

  It is obvious that the total CPU time (`user`+`sys`) is significantly higher than the elapsed wall-clock time (`real`). That indicates the parallel use of multiple cores. Keep in mind, however, that a program that is either inefficient or I/O-bound could have a low overall CPU usage *despite* using multiple cores at the same time.
- Use `top` and monitor the CPU usage percentage. This method is even less specific than `time` and has the same weakness regarding parallel programs that do not make full use of the available processing power.